# Problem with replicating Keras Binary Cross Entropy function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, generative-adversarial-network

I have a problem with the self-implementation of Keras' Binary Cross Entropy function. Before asking this question I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61488761/cant-understand-the-loss-functions-for-the-gan-model-used-in-the-tensorflow-doc) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67615051/implementing-binary-cross-entropy-loss-gives-different-answer-than-tensorflows). They are very useful, but when I implement the following code from 2nd post

```
def BinaryCrossEntropy(y_true, y_pred): 
    y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1 - K.epsilon())
    term_0 = (1 - y_true) * K.log(1 - y_pred + K.epsilon())  
    term_1 = y_true * K.log(y_pred + K.epsilon())
    return -K.mean(term_0 + term_1, axis=0)
```

on this excellent [tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/zurutech/gans-from-theory-to-production/blob/master/2.%20GANs%20in%20Tensorflow/2.1.%20Writing%20a%20GAN%20from%20scratch.ipynb#scrollTo=yKQYNIahhulH),
the results are far away from the original implementation.

To clarify more, I have written two loss functions:

```
def d_loss(real_output, generated_output):
    """The discriminator loss function."""
    bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    return bce(tf.ones_like(real_output), real_output) + bce(
        tf.zeros_like(generated_output), generated_output
    )

def new_d_loss(real_output,generated_output): 
    generated_output = K.clip(generated_output, K.epsilon(), 1 - K.epsilon())
    term_0 = (1 - real_output) * K.log(1 - generated_output + K.epsilon())  
    term_1 = real_output * K.log(generated_output + K.epsilon())
    return -K.mean(term_0 + term_1, axis=0)
```

and

```
def g_loss(generated_output):
    """The Generator loss function."""
    bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    return bce(tf.ones_like(generated_output), generated_output)

def new_g_loss(generated_output): 
    generated_output = K.clip(generated_output, K.epsilon(), 1 - K.epsilon())
    term_0 = 1  * K.log(1 - generated_output + K.epsilon())  
    #term_1 = real_output * K.log(generated_output + K.epsilon())
    return -K.mean(term_0, axis=0)
```

Original loss functions (`d_loss` and `g_loss`) work perfectly, but when I change the original one with new ones (`new_d_loss` and `new_g_loss`) results are not the same. Even when I use `new_d_loss` with original `g_loss`.